# how to allow user to input data only in first 7 day of month

Tags: php

i have create a web form to get monthly production of producers in each month. i ask them to input their previous month production data to web form in next month.
i get data entered data as follows

```
$entreddate = date("Y-m-d");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/colombo");

$enteredtime = date("H:i:s");`
```

then i get month from that date and -1 to get previous month.

but they feed data every day in next month and i was unable to finalize last month production until end of this month. is there any method to allow user to open web form only in first 7 days of next month.

Comment: Yes, you check the date before throwing the form, if it a good day, let them see the data entry form, if its a bad date, show a different page with a message saying whatever you want. _Long way from rocket science_

Comment: I wonder what the incentive is for the producer to conform to your timescales.

Comment: if(date('d') <= 7) form_output();

Comment: I think your question boils down to "how to check the current day of the month and see if it's less than 7 or not". The rest is irrelevant detail. jspit has solved it.

Comment: i use following codes to verify     <?php

$entereddate = date("Y-m-d");
$firsdate=date('Y-m-01', strtotime($entereddate));
    
$datedeferent=(strtotime($entereddate) - strtotime($firsdate));
$daysdeferent=round($datedeferent/86400);
if ($daysdeferent < 8) {
  echo "codes when Date interval  pass OK";

}
else {
  echo "output when not pass";
}
?>      is there any short method to calculate the date deference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1 -> get current date
2 -> check if it is greater than 7
3 -> if it is don't open the form otherwise open it
```

Hope that helps do let me know if it does not.

Thanks
Sagheer